# Reinterpret cast from float to int

Tags: c++

```
float f = 12.5;
unsigned int _f = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f);
std::cout << _f << std::endl; // result: 1095237632
```

Can some explain me how such casting works? And what is represented by `_f`?

**EDIT**
So this number I got `1095237632` after converting to binary is `0b1000001010010000000000000000000` and this binary number is `12.5` in IEEE-754. Do I get it right?

Comment: _"what is represented by _f?"_ Nothing. You get undefined behavior. Look that term up.

Comment: You might also be interested by the physical representation of IEEE-754, look that up.

Comment: casting did not mean conversion! any data has a representation in memory. cast tells the compiler to use the given representation as a different type. float and int have not a common representation and the cast is invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at two functions. One of them casts float to int it regularly, and one of them reinterpret casts it using reinterpret_cast:

```
int cast_to_int(float f) {
    // Rounds f to an int, rounding towards 0
    return (int)f; 
}
int reinterpret_cast_to_int(float i) {
    // Just copies the bits
    return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&i); 
}
```

So what actually happens? Let's look at the assembly:

```
cast_to_int(float):
    cvttss2si       eax, xmm0   // We cast to an int
    ret
reinterpret_cast_to_int(float):
    movd    eax, xmm0           // We directly copy the bits
    ret
```

In the first case, there's an assembly instruction that performs the conversion:

```
cast_to_int(0.7) -> 0
cast_to_int(1.0) -> 1
cast_to_int(1.5) -> 1
cast_to_int(2.1) -> 2
```

In the second case, `reinterpret_cast` just directly transforms the underlying representation of the bits. It's not actually doing anything, and the function just copyies the input register to the output register.

Under the hood, `float`s have a very different bit representation than `int`s, and that's why you're getting weird numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody can explain (*), because it does not work.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast
>   expression does not compile to any CPU instructions (except when
>   converting between integers and pointers or on obscure architectures
>   where pointer representation depends on its type). It is purely a
>   compile-time directive which instructs the compiler to treat
>   expression as if it had the type new_type.
>
> Only the following conversions can be done with reinterpret_cast,
>   except when such conversions would cast away constness or volatility.

And then follows a list of rules covering what reinterpret casts are allowed. Casting type `A` to a completely unrelated type `B` is not among them and your code exhibits undefined behaviour.

(*) Strictly speaking not true. You are treating a float as an int and if you look at their representation on your hardware and if you inspect the output of your compiler you can work out why you get the value you get, though undefined behaviour is undefined and its not worth entering details unless you are willing to write nonportable code.

Comment: For complex types, the behaviour would be undefined. For primitive types of same size, there are reasons to do such things and the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: @AntonF. I dont understand what you mean, even if `float` and `int` are of same size, reinterpreting a `float*` as an `int*` would be wrong (well actually `float*` and `int*` are of same size)

Comment: So this number I got ```1095237632``` after converting to binary is ```0b1000001010010000000000000000000``` and this binary number is ```12.5``` in IEEE-754. Do I get it right?

Comment: @irezwi you can check it eg [here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049050046053)

Answer (score -4):

As the comments below say, the usage of reinterpret_cast ist not safe for unrelated types. So don't use it this way.

First, assigning int to uint should be avoided.

For x86/x64 systemns, float is usually represented as 4 bytes, like uint32_t, and they have mostely the same alignment.

Many compilers allow the following:
    uint32_t _f = *reinterpret_cast(&f);

But this leads to undefined behavior due to some reasons (thanks for the comments):
- optimizations
- alignment
- ...

Use memcpy instead.

If alignment is the same and the values are stored in memory, the following effect desribes what happens when used reinterpret_cast:

The memory location of the 4 bytes float is &f. With a reinterpret cast to uint32_t, this memory is reinterpretet as an uint32. The dereferenced value _f contains the same bytes as the float f, but interpreted as uint32.
You could cast it back and get the original value 12.5:

```
float f = 12.5;
uint32_t _f = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
float _fnew = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&_f);
std::cout << _fnew << std::endl; // result: 12.5
```

reinterpret_cast only reinterpretes memory locations (addresses).
If the alignment is not the same or the values are stored in registers, are optimized an so on, the cast can lead to undefined values.

Comment: "float is represented as 4 bytes in memory." not necessarily. And the behaviour of your code is undefined.

Comment: "Assign to int should be avoided" is misleading. `float x = 3.5; int y = x;` is completely fine if thats what you want to do

Comment: @user463035818 If you want to reinterprete the value and not to get the casted value for some reasons, my answer seems correct to me and explains what was asked ("how such casting works").

Comment: @Bathsheba In general, you're right. I assumed x86/x64 systems (I edited my answer therefore). In a more general case, you could statically assert the size of float. Then the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: "Seems correct to me". It explicitly is _not_ allowed by the standard. I'm not sure what more can be said?

Comment: @Mike Vine: Not allowed, but other guarantees in the standard leads to correct behaviour for primitive types. If you have to do this thing, you can, even if it is not allowed. For genearl and portable things this should be avoided. I only tried to explain the mechanism, not to recommend it.

Comment: @AntonF. it is not about the size. It is about the representation in memory that is different, statically asserting the size of a float wont help a bit and you cannot magically turn what is undefined behaviour into defined behaviour

Comment: @user463035818: Please give me one reason/explanation why this would fail in real life (for primitive types). Maybe I have to update my code.

Comment: because it is defined by the standard that it is undefined behaviour. Testing it can work for one example but fail for the next. It is not just nonportable to different hardware or different compiler but you cannot even be sure if it still works if you compile the same tomorrow. Especially compiler optimizations interfer strongly with undefined behaviour in rather unpredictable way. Even if the compiler could do "the right thing" it is allowed to do whatever it likes if you dont follow the rules

Comment: @user463035818: I think you could be right especially with the optimization thing.